# SQL Server 2008: Converting rows into columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-update, pivot

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE #A (id int, cond_id int)
INSERT INTO #A (id, cond_id)
VALUES (101,20),
       (101,22),
       (101,24),
       (102,23),
       (102,22)
```

Now, each id can have max of 4 cond_ids. I want to populate table #B so that there is one id and all cond_ids will be populated in the columns as one row according to cond_id ascending.
like for id 102, cond_id 22 goes in cond_id and 23 goes in cond_id2.

```
create table #B (id int, cond_id1 int, cond_id2 int, cond_id3 int, cond_id4 int)
```

Desired result:

Table #B

```
id   cond_id1  cond_id2 cond_id3 cond_id4
101  20        22       24       null
102  22        23       null     null
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried google about PIVOT clause of t-sql

Comment: Or even looking at the Related column to the right of this post.

Comment: I can't find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you know the maximum number of columns, one option is to use `row_number`, `max` and `case`:

```
with cte as (
  select row_number() over (partition by id order by cond_id) rn, id, cond_id
  from a)
select id,
  max(case when rn = 1 then cond_id end) cond_id1, 
  max(case when rn = 2 then cond_id end) cond_id2, 
  max(case when rn = 3 then cond_id end) cond_id3, 
  max(case when rn = 4 then cond_id end) cond_id4
from cte
group by id
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9693/3)

---

Or you could look at Pivot:

```
select id, [1] cond_id1, [2] cond_id2, [3] cond_id3, [4] cond_id4
from 
   (select row_number() over (partition by id order by cond_id) rn, id, cond_id
    from a) t
pivot
(
    max(cond_id)
    for rn in ([1], [2], [3], [4])
) p
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f9693/9)